# Try-Catch not working while invoking exe through powershell

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm using microsoft's document translator msi to translate documents.I'm invoking this msi through powershell but if any error occures while processing document , script is unable to catch the error .

commandline to start instance of translator msi and translate document:

```
DocumentTranslatorCmd translatedocuments /documents:d:\testdocuments\*.docx /from:en /to:de,el
```

I tried below approaches but it looks like i'm doing something wrong :

1. using $LastExitCode

   DocumentTranslatorCmd translatedocuments /documents:d:\testdocuments*.docx /from:en /to:de,el
   if($LastExitCode -ne 0){
   do something..
   }

if error occurs during processing it does exit out of this command and control does not reaches to **if()**.So, i used exit command like :

```
 DocumentTranslatorCmd translatedocuments /documents:d:\testdocuments\*.docx /from:en /to:de,el | exit
```

2. -ErrorAction stop

   try{
   DocumentTranslatorCmd translatedocuments /documents:d:\testdocuments*.docx /from:en /to:de,el -ErrorAction stop
   }catch{
   }

if this is used **DocumentTranslatorCmd** command considering it as a argument.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As i know, i can wrong of cause, cmd commands returns  datas as a packet, powershell can't catch it, you can write a result in a variable , parse it and throw exeption

Comment: We'd need to see more of your script to be able to provide more assistance, but to my understanding, Powershell try/catch catches exceptions within the powershell script, not return codes from executables. I would think that if you need that, you'd have to throw an exception in `$LASTEXITCODE` is nonzero?

Comment: Yes $LasExitCode will work but code does not exit out  of "DocumentTranslatorCmd" command.So control will not reach out to if statement  to throw an exception. Is there any way to exit  out of this command if any error occured ?